# TextView array broken into lines

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I've added the TextViews into LinearLayout dynamically. 
The problem is that if TextViews' text are longer then Layout width they are displayed wrongly.
Is there any way that the TextViews matched the Layout width and started with new line themselves?

Comment: answer: http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

use LinearLayout.LayoutParams

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
txtView.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(txtView);
```